# When integrating the twitter framework, how do I make the submission un-editable?

Tags: xcode, twitter, uitextfield

I have a game and the user is able to submit there score to twitter. The problem is that, right now, they are able to type in whatever they want instead of their actual score. By making the TextField uneditable, they won't be able to change their score.

Anyone know a solution to this??

Here is the snippit of code (obviously the twitter framework is also applied):

```
-(IBAction)twitter {

float currentTime = [seconds.text floatValue];
float newTime = currentTime;

NSString *twitter = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"I finished level 2 of #TextOff in %.2f seconds! Think you can beat my score? Download it in the App Store now!", newTime];

TWTweetComposeViewController *tweet = [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init];
[tweet setInitialText:twitter];

//am i able to get ride of the textfield here?????

[self presentModalViewController:tweet animated:YES];
```

}

Comment: whats the point? they can still post a fully edited line from outside your app. Only difference is the client details on the tweet will be different (but how often do people check that?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make a post to Twitter using the user's Twitter account they've setup with their device **without showing the dialog or allowing them to change anything** use the Social framework's [SLRequest](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Social/Reference/SLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class.  This will allow you to make requests to Twitter w/out having to use the built in Twitter composition dialog.

Note, you have to wrap that in a [prompt to the user for Access](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Accounts/Reference/ACAccountStoreClassRef/Reference/Reference.html) with an `[ACAccountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:options:completion:]` so its a good idea to at least give them some indication of what you're doing before or after the alert prompt otherwise it would seem suspicious.